# Enabling App Insights profiler in Azure functions

Tags: azure, profiling, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to use the application insights profiler on azure functions? Either via the portal or a more manual means.

I haven't found a way in the portal and I haven't seen explicit documentation stating either way nor github tickets.

I'd assume probably not, as many of the automagic features of application insights don't seem to be supported yet.

If it's not possible, out of interest is it because of the azure functions sandbox not giving enough permissions for profiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it's not possible, out of interest is it because of the azure functions sandbox not giving enough permissions for profiling?

The [application insights profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler) is just supported in web app. The Azure function belongs to function app. So you can not use profiler in Azure function.

> Profiler currently works for ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core web apps that are running on Web Apps.

If you want to suggest Microsoft to add some new features  like app insights profiler in [app insights in azure function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/), you could put your suggestion in [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/new).

> **Next steps**
>
> Application Insights is now **GA**’d and ready for production workloads. We’re also listening for any feedback you have. Please file it on our GitHub. We’ll be adding some new features like better sampling controls and automatic dependency tracking soon.

Comment: Hi, I believe the app insights integration is GA now: "Monitoring with Azure Application Insights GA" https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/serverless-for-all-developers-bringing-azure-functions-to-linux-mac-planet-scale-nosql-real-time-analytics-and-productivity-apps/

Comment: Please see the updates. If it is helpful, you could mark it as answer to let other community members find. Thanks.

Comment: The docs says: *Profiler randomly runs two minutes every hour on each virtual machine that hosts the application that has Profiler enabled for capturing traces.* How would that work for functions in a consumption plan?